# How to control the volume of android devices through code?

Tags: android, android-layout, volume

I want to make an app which automatically puts the the phone to silent mode when the user enters certain areas (such as the academic block, library etc) in our university. I tried to search how to do this but was not able to find anything useful.

Can anyone please tell me how to this?

Comment: How would you identify the certain areas? GPS? Beacons?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Geofencing** technique for detect the particular location(on the basis of latitude and longitude). [This](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) tutorial will help  you to understand and implement the working of **Geofencing**. After detect the location you can silent the mobile phone programmatically.